# java make changes to map when iterating it

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to add new elements to Map< Integer, List < Integer >> (key is the sum and value is the numbers)

```
int c = 3;
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
                int key = entry.getKey() + c;
                List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue());
                l.add(c);
                map.put(key, l);
             }
```

Eg:
before the code    Map(3, [1, 2]) 
after              Map(3, [1, 2]  ; 6, [1, 2, 3] )

I got java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
But when i change key to constant like :  int key = 6;
it works.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Adding, removing, or editing can sometimes be problematic while using enhanced for loops, it is safe to only use them for accessing elements. Try using a regular for loop and it should fix the issue.

Comment: can you show me another way to iterate map